# Select Loses focus in IE 11 when the value is selected

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a select list on my page in side a table with alot of inline input controls.
The problem is when i change the value of input controls and press "tab" key on my keyboard the focus is shifted to the next input control but when i change the value of my select control the focus is lost completely and nothing happens when i press tab.

I have already tried using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768410/ie-11-select-with-focus-losing-focus-when-clicked) but it did not work for me.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] and describe/post what you have attempted to solve this so far? Otherwise you're essentially asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: I try to create a sample code and made a test with IE 11 but I am not able to produce the issue. Here is my testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/6qsLNwGG/122.gif So it will be better if you share the sample code which can produce the issue with IE 11. We will try to make a test with it and It can help us to narrow down the issue.